# How do I pin icons as groups?

Tags: windows-11, gui, pinning

I need to group icons like this on Windows 11, but I have not found the correct term to search for this action / how to do it.

I want several of them to stick together like shown here:

Can anybody help?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Normally you drag one icon ontop of the other, wait a bit until they group, and then release the mouse button

Comment: Note: with Windows 11, you will need to have the 22H2 update for this to work. The procedure is described [here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-organize-your-windows-11-start-menu-with-folders/).